# php - Check Session strange beahviour

Tags: php, session

EDIT: Just wanted to add that by not having 
    exit();
As pointed by zerkms and user1578653 makes this code useless and probably dangerous, it should not be used.

---

Im writing a small cms and checking to see if the user is logged in trough sessions. Every page in my backoffice has a:

```
require('includes/security.php');
```

with the following code

```
<?php

  session_start();

  session_regenerate_id();

  if (!isset($_SESSION["user_logged"]) or !isset($_SESSION["ip"]) )
   {     
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['user_logged']);
      unset($_SESSION['ip']);
      unset ( $_SESSION );
      header("location: index.php");
   }

   if ($_SESSION["ip"] !=  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])

   {
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['user_logged']);
      unset($_SESSION['ip']);
      unset ( $_SESSION );
      header("location: index.php");
   }

   if ($_SESSION["user_logged"] !=  "yes")

   {
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['user_logged']);
      unset($_SESSION['ip']);
      unset ( $_SESSION );
      header("location: index.php");
   }

?>
```

If I try to acess any page directly it works as intended and redirects me to index.php except for a single page.

This page simple takes in data from a POST and updates/deletes the images/data in the Database.

The only difference I can think about is that this page doesn't have any html, and its on the same folder as every other.

But when I try to access it directly instead of redirecting me it trows:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
Warning: session_destroy() [<a href='function.session-destroy'>function.session-destroy</a>]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session
```

This page starts exactly like this:

```
<?php

require('includes/security.php');

// Engine - Update and Delete Images
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: No other errors/warnings, especially ones relating to `session_start` (headers already sent or such like)?

Comment: `session_regenerate_id()` every run? Uhm... why? You also want to put `exit;` right after redirect.

Comment: Nope, those are the first two to show up, then it repeats over the next _Session and more strangely, it also gives Notice: Undefined index: of all the POST vars on that page.

Comment: @zerkms the cms has 4 pages to edit, wont hurt I guess.

Comment: @Marvin: "wont hurt" what? Why do you do that? Like, what is the reason you put that call to the file?

Comment: @zerkms regenerating the id provides some security, most advice is to do it with some time between. Since the use will be very spaced I dont see any negative.

Comment: "provides some security" --- it does not. "most advice is to do it with some time between" --- it makes no sense. "I dont see any negative" --- so you write weird code then ask about "strange behaviour"? You write strange code -> you get strange behaviour.

Comment: My intention was to prevent session fixation attacks, I don't see anything wrong or strange with my code. But I thank you for your time, could you please point out the disadvantages?

Comment: "the disadvantages" --- when I do something it must be proven to be necessary and efficient, not the opposite. The given solution does not provide any (like *at all*) better security to the application. So, I find weird a developer to put a function code that does not make anything useful for the application. And of course - changing session id every request is not the way you would protect against session fixation.

Comment: I believe it to be necessary, while this is not an efficient implementation. I don't see how you can affirm that it does not provide any security.

Comment: "I don't see how you can affirm that it does not provide any security" --- you cannot prove what does not exist. It's the opposite - the positive effect must be proven. But whatever - I see you the one who knows a lot about it (but cannot debug a trivial issue). So have fun!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65503/discussion-between-marvin-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is most likely trying to destroy the session multiple times (once in each 'if'). You're also doing the exact same thing in each 'if' - try changing the code in security.php to:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  session_regenerate_id();

   if(
      !isset($_SESSION["user_logged"]) || 
      !isset($_SESSION["ip"]) || 
      $_SESSION["ip"] !=  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] || 
      $_SESSION["user_logged"] !=  "yes"
   ) {     
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['user_logged']);
      unset($_SESSION['ip']);
      unset ( $_SESSION );
      header("location: index.php");
      exit();
   }
?>
```

Comment: While I understand this, why the unique behavior with a single page? Also with the conditionals it would only try to destroy it once. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the error gone away, now I only the errors relating to the undefined vars on that page. Im getting a feeling this page is corrupted.

Comment: I've slightly changed my answer - I added a call to 'exit' after the 'header' function. I believe the problems you are facing because the script continues to execute after the call to 'header'.

Comment: That solved it, but I dont understand why would the script continue.

Comment: @Marvin: why wouldn't it? There is no reason for your script to stop. Btw, I mentioned that you need `exit` 11 minutes ago, but hey - you don't read comments (and argue about "security" while it's not).

Comment: It was my belief that by pointing the header away it would stop executing the script there. I cant recall how I got that idea but it is wrong and I now see how dumb it would be.

Comment: @Marvin: `header` function just simply puts headers to the response. Nothing more.